# PHP/JavaScript web interactive atlas with data input?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, css

I apologise for the ever so slightly ambiguous title of the post, I cant quite think of the name of it, so if anyone has a better idea feel free to edit!

I am wanting to create something similar to this: http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php or something similar. I wouldnt even know where to start with this, which is a problem since I cannot google a question because of my ambiguity.

I have thorough experience with php, mediocre with javascript. I would imagine possibly using java would do this, but there shouldnt be a reason why php cannot.

Where could I start with something like this? Im looking for having a few inputs where the user can enter data and it will show with like 'weather pattern type colors' energy usage of different areas (sort of like [this](http://blogs.redding.com/smobley/archives/11-20-07-today-gfsx_500p_24h.gif))

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create your own maps and associated 'objects'. Try learn and work with existing map/geo tools like [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Again for things like weather you can choose some [API providers](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2009/04/15/5-weather-apis-from-weatherbug-to-weather-channel/) and format your map accordingly.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, please let me know if I have, but for the colouring API (if there is a pre-existing api), I dont want an actual weather thing but something that would follow the visual style of a "weather radar" kinda thing or is that what they can do? Thanks.

Comment: You can definately [color maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

Comment: Thank you I will take a look into this, if its what I need I will pop back and mark as correct